# Unable to store compressed text in MySQL

Tags: python, mysql

I am using `zlib.compress(text.encode('utf-8'))` to compress a large text and then store in mysql's `TEXT` data type. I am getting the error:

```
 Warning: (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\x9C\\xEC\\xBDy\x7f\\xDB...' for column
```

Isn't `\` already being escaped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compressed data, which is binary by definition, needs to go into a binary type column like `BLOB` or `LONGBLOB`. A `TEXT` field must be valid UTF-8 if using UTF-8 encoding.